# Authorize Google Analytics Request in Azure Website

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to make some calls to Google Analytics API from my WEB API Controller hosted in a Azure Website.

My code is this:

```
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            Service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                ApplicationName = "yoLearn"
            });
```

The path is correctly set i think:

Server.MapPath("~/Content/yoLearn-995f8379d7e4.p12")

The thing is, if i change my flag from Exportable to MachineKeySet, this exception is raised:

[image]

But if i let the Exportable flag, this happens to the website:

[image]

If anyone can help me here...i'm getting mad trying only to query to google analytics from azure website!!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This saved me...i have to add some flags to the constructor of the certificate.

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

That made the trick and the authentication runs perfectly fine